# how to update a Columns widget on urwid

Tags: python, urwid

I am starting to use urwid and one of the simple things I want to do is have two columns and being able to update one of the columns to display a different widget

I tried the following code but I keep getting an error

```
urwid.container.ColumnsError: added content invalid <Filler box widget <Text flow widget 'other test'>>
```

I just want to be able to replace

```
from urwid import *

cols = Columns([Filler(Text('test')), Filler(Text('test'))])
loop = MainLoop(cols)

cols.contents[0] = Filler(Text('other test'))
# also tried .append just for trying, same result

loop.run()
```

I am aware I could change the Text widget with ".set_text()" but that is not what I am trying to do I want to replace it with other widget.

I am starting to think this is clearly not the way it should be done but can't find anything about this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close! :)

When updating the `contents` list, you need to provide a tuple that contains both the widget and an options object (which you can construct with the `options()` method), like:

```
cols.contents[0] = (Filler(Text('other test')), cols.options())
```

See [the docs for `Columns.contents`](http://urwid.org/reference/widget.html#urwid.Columns.contents).

Comment: This is totally the answer I was looking for, I forgot about this thread but little after I asked this question I realized exactly what you mention. @elias thanks for the help :D

Comment: @academo i figured, hihi! my pleasure :)